# Syntax used in alert dialog builder

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog

I am having difficulty understanding the syntax used to invoke AlertDialog.Builder.
This piece of code is shown in this link:
https://android--code.blogspot.com/2018/02/android-kotlin-alertdialog-example.html

When he calls 
`builder.setPositiveButton()`, he uses this code:

```java
builder.setPositiveButton("YES") { dialog, which ->
   Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Ok, we change the app background.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
   root_layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
}
```

My question is:

1: What is the meaning of `dialog, which ->`?

2: When I call a method, what does it mean to pass a `{ something }`? Will it be executed together with its own function?

Thanks.

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html

Answer (score 2):

`setPositiveButton` takes two parameter, first is the button text and second is the implementation of interface `DialogInterface.OnClickListener`.

But when we see the code `builder.setPositiveButton("YES")`, method only takes one argument.

***So where is the second argument*** which should be of type `DialogInterface.OnClickListener`?

Well the block of code in curly braces after `builder.setPositiveButton("YES")` is that second argement.Because that argument is [SAM](https://www.manning.com/books/kotlin-in-action) interface and hence you can write a lambda for it, kotlin allows you to move it out of function call.

from [Kotlin In Action](https://www.manning.com/books/kotlin-in-action)

> In Kotlin, a syntactic convention lets you move a lambda expression
>   out of parentheses if it’s the last argument in a function call. In
>   this example, the lambda is the only argument, so it can be placed
>   after the parentheses:
>
> `people.maxBy() { p: Person -> p.age }`
>
> When the
>   lambda is the only argument to a function, you can also remove the
>   empty parentheses from the call:
>
> `people.maxBy { p: Person -> p.age }`

Answer (score 2):

The code is taking advantage of Kotlin's SAM conversion feature, which is just a cleaner syntax for using interfaces that only have one method (check out [this article](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-write-cleaner-code-with-kotlin-sam-conversions--cms-29304) for a good explanation). In this case, when the dialog's positive button is clicked, the following code will be executed:

```
Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Ok, we change the app background.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
root_layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
```

`dialog` and `which` are the two parameters of [DialogInterface.OnClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnClickListener.html). They could be referenced within the executed block if needed.

Written out fully, it would look like this:

```
builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Ok, we change the app background.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        root_layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
    }
});
```